# Uploading a picture with android phone gap but not sending it untill I press submit

Tags: android, cordova, camera, image-uploading

Hi I'm kind of new to developing with Phonegap.

What I'm trying to do is to have the user fill in a form and have the option of adding   picture ( from camera or from gallery). After the picture is taken I want the user to manually submit the entire form with all the fields and the picture that was chosen. My problem is that using phonegap uploads the picture immediately after it is chosen.   I have looked at  [zac vineyards code example](http://zacvineyard.com/blog/2011/03/upload-a-file-to-a-remote-server-with-phonegap) but couldn't figure out exactly how to postpone  the upload.

1. How do I postpone the upload until the user submits the form ?
2. Is the picture associated to a  specific  input field ? and how do I identify it in the server side using php I order to upload it to the server

This might be obvious to some of you but I have searched and haven't gotten a clear answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well it would be a lot easier to answer if we could see some of your code. Although all you need to do is have a submit method that does not get executed until the user clicks on the button. In that method is where you would create the FileTransfer object and upload the image and data.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see some examples for file upload [File upload Phonegap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html)